# Project deletes R.java file after importing google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, r.java-file

I have been working on a project for about a month now. It is completed and i wanted to set up ads in it. SO, after importing google play services library into the workspace when i added it into the properties of my project R.java file is getting deleted. I have made all the necessary entries in Manifest and searched a lot on the internet. Here is a part of the manifest file code. Please help!

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_personaltrainer"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Selection_page"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Is there an error when you try to build your project? The R.java file usually gets recreated on every build. If it's not created it's possible that there's a problem building the project.

Comment: Please check if any problems or warnings raised regarding version of play services and android support library

Comment: @SuneelPrakash i downloaded the latest version of google play services to ensure it isnt outdated..

Comment: @Chnoch i tried everything, restarting n all.. the funny thing is, if i remove the google play services from the properties of the project(dependencies) everything starts working find..

Comment: Have you set it up just as described on the official homepage? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup Especially adding the play services as a library?

Comment: @Chnoch yes, i did everything exactly as they have instructed.. is there any other way i can put admob ads into my app.. that is my end goal anyway..

Comment: Also try placing your project and google play services lib project on same folder

Comment: @SwapnilHarkanth I don't think you can use admob outside of the Google play services. If possible you could try migrating your build system to gradle and include the play services from there. Otherwise I can't see what's wrong, especially when there's no error message.

Comment: @Chnoch i figured out what i did wrong. While fixing the build path, i imported the entire google play services lib project instead of the jar file. Everything worked out. Thanks :)

Comment: same problem here @Swapnil Harkanth i used android-beacon-library in my project. whenever i add google-play-service in my project then R.java file deleted. whenever i remove google-play-service project working fine.
if you got any solution about this please post answer here. thanks a lot.